# how to beat computational complexity in call execute(catt(datastep))

Tags: sas, time-complexity

in a datastep of this kind

```
ID  VAR_1  VAR_2 VAR_3 ...
1   a1     b1    mv    ...
2   a2     b2    mv    ...
3   a3     b3    c3    ...
4   a4     mv    mv    ...
5   a5     b5    mv    ...
6   a6     b6    mv    ...
```

where the number of the variables are not known (i want to generalize as more as possible my code) I want to obtain a dataset like this (something like an inverted proc transpose):

```
ID VAR
1  a1
1  b1
2  a2
2  b2
3  a3
3  b3
3  c3
....
```

So i'm splitting the dataset in a nonfixed number of temp datasets, which one contains ID and only one column, trashing observation with missing values, then I'll merge all these temporary datasets obtaining my result. And this works.
But the call execute has a very high computational complexity, I mean, if I try to do this operation in a dataset with only one column (dropping missing values) my garbage computer takes 0.1 secs, while using a call execute in a dataset with 6 columns it won't take 0.1*6=0.6 secs, It will take some minutes. This because it won't work in column but in row, and this is SAS and I must get over it. But I'm asking myself (and now I'm asking to you) if there are some other ways for obtaining my results without this computational time. Here a focus on the code:

```
data _null_;                                                                                                                                                             
set old;                                                                                                                                                             
array try[*] VAR: ;                                                                                                                                                      
do i=1 to DIM(try);                                                                                                                                                      
call execute(catt("data var",i,"; set old; if var_",i," = ' ' then delete; allvarnew= col",i,";                 `                 `drop COL:; run;" ));                                                      
end;                                                                                                                                                                     
run;
```

columns are *char* $1 (ID is *char* $4).
columns are the result of a proc transpose.
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of the efficiency of this, but it requires only one data-step as opposed to the multiple data-steps in the `call execute` approach described:

```
data new (drop=var_: i);
  set test;
  array try[*] VAR_: ;
  do i=1 to DIM(try);
    var=try[i]; output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: thanks for the try!
this works!
and it's also far easier than my solution!